# how to send an array from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, arrays

```
function Perfil(){

    var metodo = "Perfil";
    $.ajax({
        url: url_header,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {Metodo:metodo, id:idUser},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP file:

```
public function Perfil(){
    try {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT tipo FROM pessoa WHERE id=".$id." ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    if($row['tipo']=="PJ"){
        $result=mysql_query("SELECT CNPJ, ValorMin, ValorMax, PossuiReserva, Descricao, foto_profile, Premium, Wifi, Id_evento_nao_premium FROM PJ WHERE ID_Pessoa= ".$id." ");
    $response  = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
        $response[] = $row;
            }
        echo json_encode($response);
     }              
     catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'O sistema retornou um erro: <br>';
    echo '<font color="#F00">'.$e->getMessage()."</font>";
     }

 }
}
```

When he enters the javascript success function it shows the following date:
[{"CNPJ":"07677711000144","ValorMin":"120","ValorMax":"500","PossuiReserva":"1","Descricao":null,"foto_profile":"","Premium":"0","Wifi":"0","Id_evento_nao_premium":"0"}]

But I knew not how it works with this information in javascript.
I've tried

```
data[0];    data["CNPJ"];
```

but nothing helped, help ..

Comment: Have you tried `data[0]["CNPJ"]`?

Comment: try to $_POST["id"]; as $_REQUEST["id"]; and add an 'exit' after  echo json_encode($response); and as you are getting a number of rows you need to get the data as an array in success function. Mean use a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that it returns a json object, instead of a string (default). You can do so by adding the dataType variable. Then the returned data is an object..

```
function Perfil(){

    var metodo = "Perfil";
    $.ajax({
        url: url_header,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {Metodo:metodo, id:idUser},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data[0].CNPJ);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

edit: You can also shorthand this:

```
$.getJSON(url_header, {Metodo:metodo, id:idUser}, function(data) { alert(data[0].CNPJ); });
```

Comment: returned in undefined alert

Comment: fixed answer, sorry, tested on jsFiddle as well to ensure the JSON is handled right: http://jsfiddle.net/WpnDs/

Comment: Tried what? This solution works and I sent a jsFiddle link proving the concept in a test. ajax function returns string by default. once dataType is set to json you can treat it as json.

Comment: I got so **var v = $.parseJSON(data.toString());
            alert(v[0].CNPJ);**

Comment: yee that works too, i also edited and added a shorthand method to do it. thank you :)